# How can I draw lines with html, css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css, draw

I'm working on a Personal web project I need to draw lines from 2 inputs to a third one.

How can I draw the lines (D in picture) using HTML, CSS and Js ?

[image]

**EDIT:** Ths inputs can be inside div blocks.

Comment: Although you could do this with typical HTML DOM elements, this is something that would be best done with either SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) or the Canvas API (drawing pictures with pixels)

Comment: https://codepen.io/uolot/pen/gmuoC may help

Comment: Please do some research before asking questions (and show the results of that research in the question) .

Answer (score 0):

Vector graphics are the best to be used whenever you need a graphical solution. But if you insist on using Javascript and such, try p5.js